# $H$ is Hilbert Space, select $x_n\in H$ such that $||x_n||=n$ then $\exists x \in H$ such that $\sup_n |(x_n,x)|=\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

$H$ is Hilbert Space and choose $x_n\in H$ such that $\|x_n\|=n$ then $\exists x \in H$ such that $\sup_n |(x_n,x)|=\infty$

**Edit:**
I did the following : To get a contradiction, Assume $\forall y, \in H \sup_n |(x_n,y)| < M \ne \infty$

And by Riesz Rep. $\forall y\in H, T_n(y)=<y,x_n>$ such that $T_n \in H'$ so $T_n$ is bounded linear functional. Indeed, $\forall y\in H, T_n(y)$ is bounded. Now, applying Uniform Bounded Theorem I can say $||T_n||$ is bounded however $||T_n||=\sup_n \frac {||T_n (y)||}{||y||}\le \sup_n \frac{||y||||x_n||}{||y||}=\sup_n ||x_n||=\sup_n n$ which is not finite. (that doesnt work)
And also $||T_n||=\sup_{||y||=1}||T_n (y)||=<y,x_n> \le ||y||||x_n||=||x_n||$
and I could not continue from here.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $x = x_n$?

Comment: I am really sorry, Now I editted the question.

Comment: Do you know the uniform boundedness principle?

Comment: yes I know. Indeed, it looks like its converse

Comment: At the end you can't conclude any contradiction because of the inequality part: any finite number is lesser than $+\infty$. Hint: what is the norm of $\|T_n\|$ equal to?

Comment: $||T_n||=\sup_{||y||=1}||T_n (y)||=<y,x_n>$. I could not move further maybe I can use Cauchy-Schwarz but again I will have inequatliy

Comment: Hint: $\|T_n\| \leq \|x_n\|$ with Cauchy-Schwarz, but isn't there an easy-to-see vector for which $|T_n(y)| = \|x_n\|\|y\|$?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Could you help me a little more? Thanks

Comment: For the future: only the poster will get pinged 100% of the time wihout an @ (though there are a few times where it works, no idea why but that's kinda cool), if you want someone to see that you talked to them you need to write "@insertnamehere" (and you can just write the first letters and let the site auto-complete, useful when user128546375445190342 says something and you don't want to type the whole name yourself). But anyway, if you pick $y = x_n$, then $T_n(x_n) = (x_n, x_n) = \|x_n\|^2 = \|x_n\|\|x_n\|$ and so, with $\|T_n\| \leq \|x_n\|$ that tells you that in fact $\|T_n\| = \|x_n\|$.

Comment: the answer in below is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you know the uniform boundedeness theorem. Try to use its contraposition with the family of continuous linear forms of $H$, $L_n : x \mapsto \left<x_n,x\right>$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider linear functionals $T_{n}(x)=\langle x, x_{n}\rangle$ then $||T_{n}||=||x_{n}||$. If for all $x\in H$ , there exists $C_{x}$ such that $\displaystyle\sup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}||T_{n}(x)||\leq C_{x}$ . Then by Uniform Boundedness Principle , there exists $C>0$ such that $\sup_{n}||T_{n}||\leq C$ . But this is not possible as $||T_{n}||=||x_{n}||=n$ which is unbounded.

Thus there must exist some $x\in H$ such that $\displaystyle\,\sup_{n}\,\langle x,x_{n}\rangle$ is unbounded.